# L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

$$
\lim_{x\to \pi/2} (2 x - \pi) \sec(x) = 0 \times \infty
$$

can be solved by putting it on the form:

$$
\lim_{x\to \pi/2} (2 x - \pi) / (1/sec(x))
$$

and by using  L'Hopital's rule. The answer will be $-2$.

"My question is can we also solving it using" L'Hopital's rule " after  putting it on the form:

$$
\lim_{x\to \pi/2} \sec(x)/(1/(2 x - \pi))
$$

Comment: Every form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ ,$\frac{0}{0}$ , $0\cdot\mp\infty$ , etc can be solved using L'Hospital's rule IF $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

write it in the form $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2x-\pi}{\cos(x)}=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{-\sin(x)}=\frac{2}{-1}=-2$$

Comment: It's clearer if you add $= \frac{2}{\sin(x)}$ after the first equality.

Comment: @Dr.Sonnhard Graubner Sorry I correct my question please check it again

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can solve it with L'Hôspital rule as well :$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}(2x-\pi)\sec(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2x-\pi}{{1}\over{\sec(x)}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{{\tan(x)}\over{\sec^2(x)\cos(x)}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2\sec^2(x)\cos(x)}{\tan(x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{{2}\over{\cos(x)}}{\tan(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\tan(x)\cos(x)}.$$
Now, because of $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan(x)\cos(x)=-1\Longleftrightarrow\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\tan(x)\cos(x)}=\frac{1}{-1}=-1.$$
Now simplify:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\tan(x)\cos(x)}=\frac{2}{-1}=-2.$$

Comment: appreciate your cooperation with me greatly....But my point is solving it starting  from the form limit sec(x)/(1/(2*x-pi); and using D.L.H

Comment: @TahaTopology It cannot be solved as sec(x)/(1/2x–π).

Comment: @TahaTopology  Some times on limits $$\frac{f(x)}{{1}\over{g(x)}}\neq\frac{g(x)}{{1}\over{f(x)}}.$$

Comment: Then I did huge mistake

Comment: @TahaTopology This one can only be solved if you transform it to the form: $$\frac{2x-\pi}{{1}\over{\sec(x)}}$$ and cannot be solved as: $$\frac{\sec(x)}{{1}\over{2x-\pi}}.$$

Comment: and the reason is ?

Comment: @TahaTopology That the derivate changes everything.

Comment: @TahaTopology There's an even easyer way. Just apply the type: $\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$. Then use L'Hôspital rule to get $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{-\sin(x)}=-2.$$

Answer (score -1):

No, because $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}(2x-\pi)\sec(x)\neq\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2x-\pi}{\sec(x)}.$$
But equal to $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sec(x)}{{1}\over{2x-\pi}}.$$

Comment: Mpalis 
 Yes thank you I correct my question ,please check it again .

Comment: Yes you can, why not ?

Comment: @TahaTopology As I said, all these  forms can be solved with L'Hôspital

Comment: using L'Hopital's rule? please can you show me how ??? when I get the derivative of sec(x)=sec(x) *tan(x) ....and 1/(2*x-pi) it will get -2/(2*x-pi)^2 .....it getting complicated ?

Comment: @Theodors Mpalis ...ok lim tan(x)/((cos(x)/-2*(2*x-pi)^(2))=inifinty/(0/infinity) ???? for me it's very hard to get (-2) ..please more explane

Comment: @TahaTopology dude, just use DLH couple of times and it can be solved.

Comment: @TahaTopology Try to solve $\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan(x)}{cos(x)}.$ Then simplify.

Comment: with all my respect are you sure ?the second derivative will be sec^(3)(x)+tan^(2) *sec(x) ? more complicated

Comment: did you mean solving lim tan(x)/cos(x) when x tends to (pi/2) using D.H.l again ...please give me the full answer .....simplify it for me ...

Comment: @TahaTopology At first, learn to write stuff with symbols. By using "$" at the start and at the and  of your equation. These are all the commands for symbols:  http://estudijas.lu.lv/pluginfile.php/14809/mod_page/content/16/instrukcijas/matematika_moodle/LaTeX_Symbols.pdf

Comment: @Theodors Mpalis ..Thank you for correct my writing and giving the link ...and I will try my best the learn it

Comment: @TahaTopology No offense, I couldn't understand what you were writing.

Comment: @TahaTopology why do you want to solve it with L'Hôspital while you can do it in easyer  ways ?

Comment: sorry I'm in getting difficulties to solve it at this form ...I want to show that it's the same if we putting (1/sec(x) ) at  denominator or putting (1/(2*x-pi)) at  denominator.....it will giving the sane result using D.L.R...@Theodoros Mpalis

Comment: @TahaTopology Check my reply bellow.

Comment: ok thank you ..but I didn't see you replay yet @Theodoros Mpalis

Comment: @TahaTopology What do u mean ? I just replied to you. Refresh the page

Comment: yes I saw your answers thank you ....but in fact i feel sorry a bout my self

Comment: @TahaTopology ? Why ?

Comment: coz my abilities in math getting down and I tell my students it can be solved at the giving form ...I live in war zone in libya ...I didn't read tomuch as past days ...sorry feel 0.@Theodoros Mpails

Comment: @TahaTopology Are you a teacher ? No worries, I feel you...

Comment: Yes ...I'm a teacher ..but in fact I become a very low level one ....@Theodoros Mpalis thank you for your helping ...I really didn't how to correct my mistake to my student this the 3th correction at this semester ...they will lose trust ....."more and more "